# pass subclass instances as superclass with Jaxb

Tags: jaxb, polymorphism, marshalling

I need to send/receive polymorphic objects from/to server while invoking my spring enabled restful service.

Please let me know if xmlseealso annotation can be useful even when there are more than 1 subclass in the class hierarchy. I'm askign this because, even though i pass 2 to 3 subclasses inside xmlseealso annotation, only the last subclass is considered when unmarshalling takes place.

like when the parent model is as below,

@XmlSeeAlso({RateFix.class, EarlyRedemption.class}) 
public class Instruction implements Serializable

jaxb2 always unmarshall the Instruction to EarlyRedemption model while it actually refers to RateFix.

I'm using jaxb 1.0 jars only where i can find the xmlseealso annotation 
Please share me your view. Thanks.

Comment: I have gone through couple of Blaise response for this kind of Qns.

Comment: unfortunately i can't try out eclipse link moxy option because system setup and also i can't go for jee6 implementation as my prj will run with jdk1.5 only.

Comment: so just want to know if at all using the sun jaxb latest API, can achieve this polymorphism while marshalling/unmarshalling. I'm new to field of jaxb & so plz help me.